Python Tkinter: Window freezing on user click during update_idletasks()
I am trying to make an app in tkinter to visualize data structures and algorithms. However, I have an issue with the way the program is updating the canvas during the visualisation process. When the visualisation process takes more than ~2 seconds, the program freezes if the user clicks on the window (not responding), and resumes when the visualisation is complete. I am sure what causes this problem, and it doesn't arise if the user never clicks. Any ideas as to the actual problem and/or issue? The app is still in a testing phase, so it isn't super clean, apologies for that.
"""Module for visualizing data structures and algorithms"""
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import HORIZONTAL


def bubble(data, draw_data, speed):
    data_length = len(data)

    for i in range(data_length):
        for j in range(0, data_length - i - 1):

            if data[j] > data[j + 1]:
                data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]

                # if swapped then color becomes Green else stays Red
                draw_data(data, ['Green' if x == j + 1 else 'Red' for x in range(len(data))])
                window.after(int(speed * 1000), bubble, data, draw_data, int(speed * 1000))

    # sorted elements generated with Green color
    draw_data(data, ['Green' for _ in range(len(data))])


window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(700, 580)

app_width, app_height = 700, 580
screen_width, screen_height = window.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()

mid_x = (screen_width - app_width) // 2
mid_y = (screen_height - app_height) // 2

window.title("StructViz")
window.iconbitmap("./assets/favicon.ico")
window.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{mid_x}+{mid_y}')

select_alg = tk.StringVar()
data = []


def regenerate():
    global data

    minval = int(minEntry.get())

    maxval = int(maxEntry.get())

    sizeval = int(amountEntry.get())

    data = []
    for _ in range(sizeval):
        data.append(random.randint(minval, maxval + 1))

    draw_data(data, ['Red' for _ in range(len(data))])


def draw_data(data, colorlist):
    structVizC.delete("all")

    canvas_height = 380
    canvas_width = 500
    x_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
    offset = 30
    spacing = 10

    normalized_data = [i / max(data) for i in data]

    for i, height in enumerate(normalized_data):
        x0 = i * x_width + offset + spacing
        y0 = canvas_height - height * 340

        x1 = ((i + 1) * x_width + offset)
        y1 = canvas_height

        structVizC.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=colorlist[i])
        structVizC.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor='se', text=str(data[i]))
    window.update_idletasks()


def start_algorithm():
    global data
    bubble(data, draw_data, speedbar.get())


window.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=45)
window.rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(2, weight=45)

navbarLB = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
for item in ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]:
    navbarLB.insert(tk.END, item)
navbarLB.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky='nsew')

userSettingsF = (tk.Frame(window, background='bisque2')
                 .grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='news', padx=7, pady=5))

# Change navbarLB.get(0) when user generates a selected option ( from func selected_item() )
AlgorithmL = tk.Label(userSettingsF, text=navbarLB.get(0), background='bisque2')
AlgorithmL.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

amountEntry = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=5, to=40, label='Amount', background='bisque2',
                       orient=HORIZONTAL, resolution=1, cursor='arrow')
amountEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='n', padx=10, pady=10)

minEntry = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=0, to=10, resolution=1, background='bisque2',
                    orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Minimum Value")
minEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='s', padx=10, pady=10)

maxEntry = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=10, to=100, resolution=1, background='bisque2',
                    orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Maximum Value")
maxEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='se', padx=10, pady=10)

speedbar = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=0.10, to=2.0, length=100, digits=2, background='bisque2',
                    resolution=0.1, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Speed")
speedbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ne', padx=10, pady=10)

tk.Button(userSettingsF, text="Start", bg="Blue", command=start_algorithm, background='bisque2').grid(
    row=1, column=1, sticky='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

tk.Button(userSettingsF, text="Regenerate", bg="Red", command=regenerate, background='bisque2').grid(
    row=1, column=1, sticky='sw', padx=10, pady=10)

structVizC = tk.Canvas(window, background='bisque2')
structVizC.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='news', padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()

During visualisation the app should display the process. On user click, it should do nothing. Instead, it freezes (not responding) until the process is complete.

Better use window.after() instead of time.sleep()

Using window.after doesn't seem to provide a different result from time.sleep. Clicking on the window still makes it freeze until the process is done.

@Harbourheading using after with only 1 argument is the same as time.sleep. Use it with a callback like this. If you are already using that, please edit your question with the new code.

@TheLizzard I updated the code to what I believe was the solution you requested? However, now the code doesn't seem to actually run at the speed I set instead. I did put the scale/size of the algorithm to a larger one to test whether it still froze when clicking after ~2 seconds, and it did.

if you run long-running code then every GUI (not only tkinter) will freeze. Inside bubble you have nested for-loops with window.after(... bubble) - so it starts new bubble in every loop - so it may run many bubble at the same times - and this may kill your program. You should rather use  window.after(... bubble)after allfor-loop - to run only one bubble`

other problem can be because in nested for-loops you run draw_data - so it has to redraw all plot after every pixel. And this may also kill your program. Better draw it after every line. or even after all for-loops

code works correctly for me when I use window.update() instead of window.update_idletasks() or when I use both

to control speed it needs window.after(int(speed * 1000)) without other parameters. But for bigger values it freeze code. It wound need to organize all code in different way. It would have to exit function after every inner loop - but this makes problem to keep information about values from for-loops

@furas Thank you so much for the valuable information! Seems switching out window.update_idletasks() with window.update() worked. I'll see about reorganizing the code to make it more efficient in drawing though. Thanks again : )

I already have working code - it use yield to exit for-loops (after running window.after()) and later it can continue it in the same place. And finally I don't need window.update_idletasks() with window.update()

GUI doesn't freeze when I use window.update() instead of window.update_idletasks() or when I use both together.
But real problem is bubble() which runs window.after(...) but it never exit bubble() after window.after() and it can't make delay before next drawing - so it can't control speed. And this also makes problem with update_idletasks().
It needs to exit nested loops but it makes problem how to jump back into nested loop. And this may need to use yield which can exit function and later it can start function after yield instead of starting from the beginning.
Here bubble() with yield but without window.after()
def bubble(data, draw_data):
    data_length = len(data)

    for i in range(data_length):
        for j in range(0, data_length - i - 1):

            if data[j] > data[j + 1]:
                data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]
                draw_data(data, ['Green' if x == j + 1 else 'Red' for x in range(data_length)])
                yield
    
    # sorted elements generated with Green color
    draw_data(data, ['Green' for _ in range(len(data))])

    # here python runs as default `return None`

And here function which runs bubble() and it uses window.after()
generator = None

def repeater(data, draw_data, speed):
    global generator
    
    # run it only once - at start
    if not generator:
        generator = bubble(data, draw_data)

    try:
        # run function - it will raise `StopIteration` when it use `return` instead of `yield`
        next(generator)  
        
        # set next execution after some time
        window.after(speed, repeater, data, draw_data, speed)     
        
        # exit this function
        return
    except StopIteration:  # 
        # reset value after last execution 
        generator = None

And now button starts repeater instead of bubble
def start_algorithm():
    repeater(data, draw_data, int(speedbar.get()*1000))

And now it can run with different speeds.
And it also works correctly without window.update() and window.update_idletasks()

Full working code.
I increased Amount to 100, and reduced Speed to 0.01 - to see faster animation with more values.
I also added boolean variable running_animation to stop animation when you press again button Start during animation. But it works rather like pause because when you press it again then it continues animation. I use it also to stop animation when you press Regenerate but it needs some changes to work correctly.
import random
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

# --- functions ---

def bubble(data, draw_data):
    data_length = len(data)

    for i in range(data_length):
        #print('i:', i)
        for j in range(0, data_length - i - 1):
            #print('j:', j)

            if data[j] > data[j + 1]:
                data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]
                draw_data(data, ['Green' if x == j + 1 else 'Red' for x in range(data_length)])
                #print('before yield')
                yield
                #print('after yield') 

    #print('finish')
    # sorted elements generated with Green color
    draw_data(data, ['Green' for _ in range(len(data))])

generator = None

def repeater(data, draw_data, speed):
    global generator
    
    if not generator:
        generator = bubble(data, draw_data)

    try:
        #print('next')
        next(generator)
        
        if running_animation:
            #print('after:', )
            window.after(speed, repeater, data, draw_data, speed)     
        else:
            generator = None
        
        #print('return')
        return
    except StopIteration:
        #print('StopIteration')
        generator = None

def regenerate():
    global data
    global running_animation
    
    print('regenerate')

    if running_animation:
        running_animation = False
        
    minval = int(minEntry.get())
    maxval = int(maxEntry.get())
    sizeval = int(amountEntry.get())

    data = []
    for _ in range(sizeval):
        data.append(random.randint(minval, maxval + 1))

    draw_data(data, ['Red' for _ in range(len(data))])


def draw_data(data, colorlist):
    print('draw')
    
    structVizC.delete("all")

    canvas_height = 380
    canvas_width = 500
    x_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
    offset = 30
    spacing = 10

    normalized_data = [i / max(data) for i in data]

    for i, height in enumerate(normalized_data):
        x0 = i * x_width + offset + spacing
        y0 = canvas_height - height * 340

        x1 = ((i + 1) * x_width + offset)
        y1 = canvas_height

        structVizC.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=colorlist[i])
        structVizC.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor='se', text=str(data[i]))
    
    #window.update_idletasks()
    #window.update()

def start_algorithm():
    global running_animation 
    
    if not running_animation:
        running_animation = True
        repeater(data, draw_data, int(speedbar.get()*1000))
        start_button['text'] = 'Stop'
    else:
        running_animation = False
        start_button['text'] = 'Start'

# --- main ---

running_animation = False

window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(700, 580)

app_width, app_height = 700, 580
screen_width, screen_height = window.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()

mid_x = (screen_width - app_width) // 2
mid_y = (screen_height - app_height) // 2

window.title("StructViz")
#window.iconbitmap("./assets/favicon.ico")
window.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{mid_x}+{mid_y}')

select_alg = tk.StringVar()
data = []


window.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=45)
window.rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(2, weight=45)

navbarLB = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
for item in ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]:
    navbarLB.insert(tk.END, item)
navbarLB.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky='nsew')

userSettingsF = (tk.Frame(window, background='bisque2')
                 .grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='news', padx=7, pady=5))

# Change navbarLB.get(0) when user generates a selected option ( from func selected_item() )
AlgorithmL = tk.Label(userSettingsF, text=navbarLB.get(0), background='bisque2')
AlgorithmL.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

amountEntry = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=5, to=100, label='Amount', background='bisque2',
                       orient="horizontal", resolution=1, cursor='arrow')
amountEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='n', padx=10, pady=10)

minEntry = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=0, to=10, resolution=1, background='bisque2',
                    orient="horizontal", label="Minimum Value")
minEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='s', padx=10, pady=10)

maxEntry = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=10, to=100, resolution=1, background='bisque2',
                    orient="horizontal", label="Maximum Value")
maxEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='se', padx=10, pady=10)

speedbar = tk.Scale(userSettingsF, from_=0.01, to=1.0, length=100, digits=3, background='bisque2',
                    resolution=0.01, orient="horizontal", label="Speed")
speedbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ne', padx=10, pady=10)

start_button = tk.Button(userSettingsF, text="Start", bg="Blue", command=start_algorithm, background='bisque2')
start_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

tk.Button(userSettingsF, text="Regenerate", bg="Red", command=regenerate, background='bisque2').grid(
    row=1, column=1, sticky='sw', padx=10, pady=10)

structVizC = tk.Canvas(window, background='bisque2')
structVizC.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='news', padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()


+1 Nice technique using an iterator to convert the nested for loops into a tkinter after loop. Also you can avoid using global generator if you pass it in as an optional argument instead. Furthermore, you can even make it into its own class that just takes any iterator and uses .after().

@TheLizzard I was thinking about class to hide generator, and about few other changes but it would be too much changes in this code. Iterator may be big change for OP if OP didn't use it before :) So I keep only more important changes.
